# Unit path compiled in executable

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I noticed that in compiled exe there are hard-coded paths to 3rd party components units.
For example, if I use VirtualTrees component, TVirtualStringTree, in compiled executable I can find this path several times:

```
C:\Program Files\Borland\Delphi7\Source\Virtual Treeview\Source\VirtualTrees.pas
```

This applies to almost all 3rd party components I use, paths to component's units in exe.
I think this information should not be in executable, but don't know what I have to change in Delphi 7 settings, or in project's settings, to get rid of it.
Does anyone have a solution please?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you see are the assertion messages keeping the source of the assert. You can disable them if you go to `Project / Options` or using <kbd>CTRL + SHIFT + F11</kbd> shortcut which opens the project options dialog.

There uncheck the `Assertions` check box in the `Compiler` tab, save the project options and rebuild the project. Not recompile, but rebuild!

[image]

The paths in your binary you will see always when you use [`Assert`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Assert) when you'll have that option turned on.

Comment: You're welcome! Anyway, you should keep the assertions enabled in your debug environment and turn them off just when you're going to build a release version. That can be easily done from a batch file build script.

Comment: @Shadi: Keeping asserts on can actually be very useful.  Your internal testing will never catch every possible error condition, and having assertions around provides protection against data corruption.  (It's even more useful if you're also using an error reporting tool, like MadExcept or EurekaLog.)

Comment: @MasonWheeler +1 for your comment. IMHO assertions are not to be confused with unit testing, and should always be left enabled. An assertion should check something which may *break* the execution due to a code logic, like an un-set parameter or an invalid sequence call to a method. Such logic issues can not be defined at compile time, but could be tracked with assertions at run-time. This is something diverse to unit-testing.